# Scraping inconsistent search results with PHP

Tags: php, curl, xpath, web-scraping, scrape

How can I scrape a list of search results, with an inconsistent amount of items?

**Here is an example:**

In this search result you will find 4 businesses:
https://www.11880.com/suche/0521441422/deutschland

Now, not each of those 4 businesses has an opening hour information included:
The first one doesn't and the last 3 businesses have the opening hour information included.

So if I try to do it with the script below, the opening hour information gets related to the wrong business => it gets "connected" with the first 3 businesses, instead of the last 3 businesses.

How can I modify the script, so that the opening hours are connected to the correct business?

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20120101 Firefox/33.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.11880.com/suche/0521441422/deutschland');
$page = curl_exec($ch);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($page);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$results = [];
$results['name'] = $xpath->query('//h2[@itemprop="name"]');
$results['street'] = $xpath->query('//span[@class="street-address"]');
$results['zipcode'] = $xpath->query('//span[@class="postal-code"]');
$results['city'] = $xpath->query('//span[@class="address-locality"]');
$results['district'] = $xpath->query('//span[@class="quarter"]');
$results['opening_hours'] = $xpath->query('//span[@class="open-or-closed"]');


//*[@id="html-search-result-list"]/li[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/span[1]
#html-search-result-list > li:nth-child(3) > div > div.row-result-entry--bottom.row > div.col-result-entry-content--contactinfos.hidden-xs.col-sm-8 > span.btn-ghost.btn-ghost-primary.btn-result-entry-interaction.open-or-closed.open

for($x=0; $x < $results['name']->length;$x++)
{
  echo trim($results['name']->item($x)->textContent) . ";";
  echo trim($results['street']->item($x)->textContent) . ";";
  echo trim($results['zipcode']->item($x)->textContent) . ";";
  echo trim($results['city']->item($x)->textContent) . ";";
  echo trim($results['district']->item($x)->textContent) . ";";
  echo trim($results['opening_hours']->item($x)->textContent) . "<br>\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in such way. It's just a draft

```
// Find parent divs
$divs = $xpath->query('//h2[@itemprop="name"]/ancestor::div[1]');
for($x=0; $x < $divs->length;$x++) {
   // Find items, you want, inside div
   $name = $xpath->query('.//h2[@itemprop="name"]', $divs[$x]);
   if ($name) {
      echo trim($name->item(0)->textContent) . ";";
   }
// ...
}
```